FedEx REST Rating API "Non-Standard Package" indicator
When you use the FedEx online rating calculator
https://www.fedex.com/en-us/online/rating.html#
after you get a base price for the shipment, there is an option to refine the quote by checking a box that says "I'm shipping non-standard package(s)"
I don't see a way to specify this in the REST Rating API.  Has someone figured out how to do this?

